# Direct product of groups which is isomorphic to one of the factors?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've gotten stuck on a problem in Aluffi's Algebra book (problem 2.3.4). It reads, verbatim:

Let $G,H$ be groups, and assume that $G \cong H \times G$. Can you conclude that $H$ is trivial? (Hint: No. Can you construct a counterexample?)

Clearly the order of $G$ cannot be finite, otherwise, by inspecting the order of the underlying set of $G\times H$, we can conclude immediately that $|H|=1$. My spidey senses are failing me beyond this. I've already checked Aluffi's list of errata, which has been pretty complete as near is I can tell thus far and this problem is not on the list. Could some kind soul please unstick me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $H$ is not necessarily trivial, think $G=R^{\infty}, H=R$

Comment: Ah, yes. I see now. This can be generalized to any $G\times G^{k} \cong G^k \Rightarrow k \equiv k+1 \Rightarrow |k|\geq \aleph_0$.